# open vim from C system command

Tags: c, shell, vim

I am noobie with C.

I've seen `system()` and `fork()` and `execv()` stuff, but I do not think they are what I need ( or they just do not work )

I just want to my C program to open vim immediately of a file path to edit, then i can quit vim and the program continues, in my case it will just exit.

Think like `git commit`, it opens vim for me then when I save+exit it sends the commit.

Any ideas?

Comment: `system()` sounds appropriate, as long as you are ok that your program is blocked at the time `vim` is running

Comment: Since you're mentioning git, https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/commit.c

Comment: What went wrong with trying to use `system`, or any of the functions you've mentioned? `system`, or some form of `fork` + `exec*` + `wait*` would work just fine. As it stands this isn't a very appropriate question for SO (no code, no attempts). You should try to solve the problem first, and ask questions when you actually get stuck.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for these comments - i just wasn't using `system()` right! Thanks for that github link too and everything, I appreciate this guys

Comment: Can you post your solution below for other people looking for an answer in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System(3)` will do the work, but beware that if you call your program with the input/output redirected not to a terminal, this will propagate to the execution of `vim` and it will not work.

`vim(3)` requires that the input and output are directed to a terminal line, it cannot work on redirected input, so the best way to call it should be (with `system()`):

```
system("/usr/bin/vim file </dev/tty >/dev/tty");
```

The redirection clauses specify that the input and the output be redirected to the session controlling terminal, so you'll get it working even if you have redirected standard input/output in the main program.

Answer (score 2):

`system()` is what I was looking for, I was using it incorrectly, but it's simple just use:

```
system("vim path/to/file.txt");
```

will open vim of current directy and work like expected ( like `git commit` )